# What does this notation mean? ($g\dot x$)

Tags: notation

My textbook (nonlinear dynamics and chaos, strogatz), uses Green's theorem at some point (the actual use is not relevant for my question I hope):

> given a real valued function $g(\vec x)$ such that $\nabla\cdot (g\dot x)$ [...] then using Green's theorem,
>   $$\int\int_A\nabla\cdot(g\dot {\vec x})dA=\int_Cg\dot {\vec x }\cdot n  dl $$ where

What does $g\dot {\vec x}$ mean here? $g$ is a function, so why isn't it written $g(\dot {\vec x})$? There must be a difference between the meaning of these two notations.

Comment: It may mean $g\cdot \frac{dx}{dt}.$ Physicists use dots for derivatives sometimes.

Comment: I know what the $\dot x$ means. my confusion is about $g$

Comment: You're just taking the argument of div to be $g$ times $\dot x$.

Comment: So you're saying $g\dot {\vec x}$ means $g(\vec x)*\dot {\vec x}$?